# jquery bind an event inside a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

cutting straight to the chase:

I have a really large function inside of which I have an element that under certain conditions is given some css attributes, one of which is height and position:fixed.

The function is run by the use of a click, but I want this element inside it to be bind with the window resize event.

I was thinking about creating a second function by finding one of this element's attributes -in this case position:fixed - and if it has it, then bind it with the window resize.

I guess this is not the best solution so I thought I'd ask the pros. Giving a sample code:

```
whh=$(window).height();

$('#open').click(function(){
$('#mybody').attr('style', 'position:fixed !important;overflow-y:scroll;overflow-x:hidden;height:' + whh + 'px;');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
  var position = $( "#mybody" ).css( "position" );
  if (position == 'fixed') {
  // do your stuff
  }
});
```

Comment: Yup, exactly what I was after. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

First, keep the same code but instead of setting style attribute, add a css classe like.

```
$("#mybody").addClass("truc");
```

And of course, define the css class

```
.truc : {
    position:fixed !important;
    ....
}
```

For the rest, I didn't understand :s

Comment: this is absolutely irrelevant plus I need the inline styling to override a style

Comment: I thought the first "C" was for cascading, sorry for my mistake.